# Custom claim rules

Tags: adfs, claims

i'm new to ADFS claim rules and struggling with a custom rule.

What i want to do is filter groups based on group names, and then return the matched groups as SIDs. I also want to return UPN, Email, Surname, GivenName and WindowsAccountName along with these, but the filtered groups are most important.

I've tried this with no success:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value =~ "(?i).+(Test|Test2).+"]
=> issue(Type = "https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid");
```

Can anyone help me creating this rule or point me in the right direction? I would also appreciate an explanation of the rule if you bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the user params i want, filters groups based on names, and returns groups as both unqualified names and SIDs

Get groups:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group"), query = ";tokenGroups;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

Filter and issue groups:

```
c1:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value =~ "INSERT-REGEX-HERE"]
 && c2:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group"), query = "(&(name={0}));objectSid,name;{1}", param = c1.Value, param = c2.Value);
```

Issue user params:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname"), query = ";givenName,sn,mail,userPrincipalName,sAMAccountName;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need a rule to create the groups.

So in the wizard, set an LDAP rule.

On the LHS, choose, "Token-Groups - Unqualified Names".

On the RHS, choose "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group".

You now have something to run the regex on.

c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value =~ "(?i).+(Test|Test2).+"]
=> issue(Type = "https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", Value=c.value);

What the rule says is take all claims of type "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", run the regex, if true, create a groupsid claim with the value of the Group claim.

Note that if more than one group matches the regex, you will get multiple claims of type groupsid.

Also, look here for [reference](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/adfs-claims-rules-c8e877faf352).

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. We tried this, but it just returns the group name under the claim https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid, not the SIDs itself. Any other ideas?

Comment: Use "Token-Groups as SIDs"

Comment: When using Token-Groups as SIDs i cant filter on group names. Updating the question with my solution.